# Sum Pivot Table's Column Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 5 tables: `sales_orders`, `product_sales_order` (pivot table between `sales_orders` and `products`), `products`, `shipment`, and `product_shipment` (pivot table between `shipment` and `products`).

##### `SalesOrder.php`

```php
class SalesOrder extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
            ->using(ProductSalesOrder::class)
            ->withPivot(['qty', 'price']);
    }

    public function shipments()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Shipment::class);
    }
}
```

##### `ProductSalesOrder.php`

```php
class ProductSalesOrder extends Pivot
{
    public function getSubTotalAttribute()
    {
        return $this->qty* $this->price;
    }
}
```

##### `Shipment.php`

```php
class Shipment extends Model
{
    public function salesOrder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SalesOrder::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
            ->withPivot(['qty']);
    }
}
```

[image: ER Diagram]

**Here what I want to achieve**

Since 1 `sales_order` able to ship the `product` several times, I need to know how many products that already shipped before. And when I create new shipment, I need to limit the maximum qty that can be send at that time.

In this case, `sales_order` has 2 products with order qty 100 pcs each. Yesterday, I create 2 `shipment` which is 25 pcs and 50 pcs for `product` A. When I want to create new shipment for today, I can only send 25 pcs for product A and 100 pcs for product B.

I've tried my own way, using nested foreach and store the value that I want to an array. But is it possible to sum the qty inside `product_shipment` and compare it with the qty that has been ordered using `eloquent`?